# Pandas Series.replace on boolean Series

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

input

```
Series([True, False, True]).replace('fdsa','lkjh')
```

output

```
0     lkjh
1    False
2     lkjh
dtype: object
```

I would expect:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

This makes it quite annoying to work with boolean data. What is the reasoning behind the current behaviour?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That is very strange. I cant figure out why it is doing that. If you roll back to version 0.12 it handles the Series replace correctly. Maybe raise an issue on Github?

Comment: its a trivial fix, see the issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6332 (can also do ``s.astype(object).replace(....)``

Comment: FYI This is now fixed in pandas master https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6339.