# Why does pandas Series.replace change the data type when to_replace includes nan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a reason why adding `{nan: nan}` changes the data type in `Series.replace`? If yes, what is the intent of having such a behaviour?

This is what I expected:

```
from pandas import Series
from numpy import nan

series = Series(['Y', 'N', 'Unknown', nan])
series.replace({'Y': False, 'N': True, 'Unknown': nan})

0    False
1     True
2      NaN
3      NaN
dtype: object
```

And this is what I got after adding an "innocent" identity mapping of `NaN`:

```
series.replace({'Y': False, 'N': True, 'Unknown': nan, nan: nan})
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

The example looks silly out of the context - in reality, the identity mapping was introduced incidentally when the mapping dictionary (also used elsewhere in the code) was modified.

Background: I am cleaning a DataFrame that includes both NaNs and  "Unknown". As each column is considered on its own (sometimes *Unknown* is the desired value!) I did not instruct pandas to treat "Unknown" as NaN during data loading.

Related:
[Pandas Series.replace on boolean Series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21733802/6646912) (5 years old, not related to NaNs and fixed)

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using? I am not able to reproduce the same behavior - both `.replace()` statements produce identical output with the datatype as `object` using version 0.22.

Comment: Pandas 0.24.2 and Python 3.7.2